# JUnit: Mocking a http server

Tags: unit-testing, rest, junit, mocking

I have a service that has a method that makes a rest call using `apache httpclient`. I want to test the call using `junit` but i do not want to mock out the call but mock out the server that it is making the call to

My question is, is it possible to mock out a server using something like `mockwebserver` so that if you make a request to a specific url that this will be picked up from the service (without mocking the service) rather then going off to the real server?

Comment: You could use Jetty or `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`. However, in my opinion this would not improve quality of the tests (when compared to using a mock) but could affect their readability and execution time (not to mention problems like making sure the port used in tests is not already used, etc.)

Comment: so would you suggest mocking the service out and mocking the calls to the server?

Comment: Yes, that would make your test a pure unit test (no collaborators involved), but ultimately it's up to you to decide which approach works better and "feels" correct.

Comment: You need to mock an HTTP server only if you are writing code that is meant to be implementing the client part of HTTP. But as you are using the Apache HTTP client, you do not need to do that. You only have to show that you have called the Apache client code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is an interface so you can return a mock in your tests.